# MySQL server parameters default empty string to null

Tags: mysql, insert, null, parameter

How can I set MySQL server parameters to default empty strings to null on insert?

is this possible?

Comment: Why would you try to do that? What is then end result you are aiming for? Are you looking for database settings or server wide settings? What should happen with other datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that by changing a server parameter. NULL is different from an empty string so there is no reason to have that.

You could change your application to send NULL to your SQL statement or add a condition to your query.

```
INSERT INTO table (column1) values (IF(LENGTH('$variable')=0,NULL,'$variable'));
```